# Writing Vector to file by dereferencing iterator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, stl, iterator

I am writing the contents of vector to a file through iterator as fallows

```
for(vector<Student>::iterator itr=vec.begin();itr!=vec.end();itr++){
    out.write((char*)itr,sizeof *itr);
}
```

It's giving compile time error as no suitable conversion function exists.But when I dereferenced itr and taken its address as below

```
out.write( (char*)&(*itr),sizeof *itr);
```

its working fine. 
       So why here I can't use itr directly? Why I need to dereference it and take its address again?

Comment: De-referencing `itr` gives you a `Student`, not a pointer.

Comment: This is the wrong way to serialize objects. In particular, if your object has any virtual members, reading the object back in later will result in an object with a bad vtable.

Comment: You must write a function to output each member one by one. Sorry.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes,dereferencing itr will give me a Student but taking its address won't it give me itr again ? So is there difference between itr and &(*itr)?

Comment: @Neil Kirk Ok.I will try this.How this can be advantageous?

Comment: @bhushanblaster: Indeed, `itr` and `&*itr` are _not_ the same here! This is one of the pitfalls of operator overloading.

Comment: @bhushanblaster By working?

Comment: Yeah.Advantages of outputting members one by one instead of whole Object directly.btw is that what you meant right?

Comment: @NeilKirk got your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just byte-by-byte serialise complex objects like this, but your attempt doesn't even try to do that!

Your first example attempts to take an *iterator*, cast it to a `char*` (which is completely nonsensical) then write `sizeof(Student)` worth of bytes starting at that nonsensical pointer into a file.

Your second example bypasses the helpful compiler errors telling you about your mistake, and *forces* the cast. Sure, you get a result, but it's a total nonsense result and your program could even crash.

Firstly, you should be attempting to serialise the `Student` objects, not the iterators that point to them, and secondly, unless they are very simple objects and you know what you're doing, you're still going to need much more intelligent serialisation logic than just writing their component bytes into a file. Learn about alignment, padding, endianness, indirection....

Comment: Ok.So can you please give a best/safe way to serialize a vector or possibly a resource to know more about this.That will be helpful.

Comment: yeah sure.thanks for some keywords though from above answer.It will narrow my search.Thank you very much.